# How to set screen resolution in a Docker Windows container?

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10

I have a windows GUI application running in a windowsservercore image, after supplying a few additional DLLs. The goal is to run the application via a script to gather text and graphical output for test cases. I have no need to actually see or interact with the GUI.

I am able to get screen captures, which is important to our legacy test case suite, but they are at the wrong resolution. Is there any way to change the resolution for either the image or container?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am trying to do the same thing

Comment: Unfortunately, no